# Ember Js Apps wihtout server

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, scorm

Anybody know if Ember Js Apps can be run without server ? i have some solution before which is:

1. Using Ember non-CLI (Ember 1.10)  => WORK
2. Using "ember build" => WORK, but only if you put it into a server like nginx

My problem is to put Ember Apps into SCORM for LMS.

When i try the solution number 1, it can work, but it have some disadvantages, its the oldest Ember version that still have the documentaion, since its the oldest version, there will be many more other disadvantages.

When i try the solution number 2, it cann't work, what i got from what i learn about SCORM is SCORM assume my Ember App as a static HTML, since my Ember App is loaded in an iframe.

I dont know why Ember App that already build by "ember build" command still cant be run without a server.

Any solution to my problem guys ? Really appreciate any suggestion that related to my problem :)

Comment: Your question is poorly worded. Please read the SO guidelines. You should outline what you have tried with an example is applicable, and the problem you are encountering.

Comment: What do you mean by "SCORM assume my Ember App as a static HTML"? If a browser can render a page when opened directly, it can render it in an iframe -- no need to assume anything. I can image permission trouble (CORS & co) when the API requests come from an app in an iframe somewhere but the API was configured to accept them only from elsewhere, but if that is the problem here, it may not even be related to ember and you need to describe what you tried, what you expected and what you saw (browser network communication & console log, not just " it cann't work").

Answer (score 2):

After you build the app with `ember build` it can be run without `ember s`. In the `dist` folder there is an index.html file and when you open it, you should see your app running without a server. You can then copy those script/style assets to a server somewhere (like s3) then in any html page, you could include links to those assets on s3 and when you open that html in a browser (or in an iframe) it should work.